# If statements aren't running and has no errors (Unity C#)

Tags: c#, if-statement, unity-game-engine

None of the if statements are running, what should I do?
All public variables are already asigned a value.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class OpeningCutscene : MonoBehaviour {
    public int scroll;
    public Text talk;
    public GameObject textS;
    public GameObject player;
    public int banana = 0;
    public int stuff = 1;
    public GameObject smartHELP;
    public GameObject smartRun;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        player.SetActive(false);
        this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        smartRun.SetActive(false);
        this.gameObject.transform.position = new         Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - 0.9f, transform.position.z);
        textS.SetActive(true);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (stuff == 1) {
            if (scroll < 300) {
                talk.color = Color.red;
                talk.text = "Hello?";
            } else if (scroll > 300 && scroll < 600) {
                talk.text = "WAKE UP!";
            } else {
                talk.text = "";
                stuff += 1;
            }
            scroll += 1;
            Debug.Log("hi...");

        }
        if (stuff == 2)
        {
            if (banana != 90)
            {
                transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1));
                this.gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + 0.01f, transform.position.z);
                banana += 1;
            }
            else if (banana == 90)
            {
                Debug.Log("Hi");
                stuff = 3;
                player.SetActive(true);
                this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                smartRun.SetActive(true);
                smartHELP.SetActive(false);
            }
        } 
        if (stuff == 3)
        {
            Debug.Log("hi");
            smartRun.transform.position = new Vector3(smartRun.transform.position.x + 1.0f, smartRun.transform.position.y, smartRun.transform.position.z);

        }
    }
```

Yes, this is not the most **compact version** but still.

And also please can anyone link to any website which I can use to learn Unity C#(Like codeacademy) and must be free.

Comment: What makes you believe the `if` statements are not running?

Comment: Did you debug this and see what `stuff` is? I guess it is zero.

Comment: By the way, `stuff` is a horrible variable name!

Comment: Is the according GaneObject in the Scene active and the component enabled?

Comment: Besides .. use `switch` everytime you only check one variable for different values

Comment: Is the gameobject to which this script is attached to, set to active?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your stuff variable in Start() Method.
Do that, for all of your initializations.

Btw, if scroll = 300, then your 3rd statement will run:

```
else {
  talk.text = "";
  stuff += 1;
}
```

I would suggest a code refactoring :)

Comment: Why would he initialize the values of his public fields in Start()? That way all his configuration from the Inspector would be overwritten..!

Comment: What do you mean(I suck at coding(begginer)) I understand the else issue but the problem is that the if statement is not even running.

Comment: @ThomasHilbert, i don't mean values initialized from editor, but the ones like stuff,  banana.

Digger,  i'm pretty sure that variable stuff, do not have a value when your game starts. So, try to initialize it inside Start() method that is provided by Unity.
void Start(){  stuff=1; }

In addition to that, in Update() method, when comparing the same variable, in your case the 'stuff', use if-else and not if-if statements.
If-else makes exclusive checks, while if-if makes all the checks.

Comment: @NikosGiannaras also `if-else` is not efficient because it still goes through all checks until one condition applies. It would be better to use `switch-case` here. `stuff` and `banana` are `public` and therefore will appear in the Inspector and might have a different start value than the one in the script. OP probably wouldn't like to overwrite it in `Start` in such a case.

Comment: I figured out the issue(wasn't active) but the last conditional statement won't load. Even if stuff = 3